# How to calculate the line impedance for WLAN antenna path and how to determine which kind of antenna is efficient for automotive product

Tags: rf, antenna, pcb-antenna

I would like to know how to calculate RF antenna Line impedance, and makes the Pi filter values exactly in my Antenna path.

I need a general guidelines and clear understanding of it. Please help me on this, thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried googling the antenna to see what you can find? Have you looked at an example data sheet of the antenna?

Comment: http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/microstrip

Comment: also, http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/microstrip-patch-antennas

Answer (score 1):

The characteristics of a PCB trace antenna are not typically calculated by hand.  Usually one uses EM solver software that can do finite element analysis based on your actual trace geometry.